# pandoc unable to display greek symbols

Tags: markdown, pandoc

Pandoc is not rendering greek symbols. When I type the following code

```
echo '$\mu' | pandoc -o output.html
```

displays nothing but a $ sign in the resulting HTML page. I tried it with &mu and other variations.

pandoc version - 2.2.3.2

Answer (score 1):

LaTeX is only interpreted if it is in a math environment, which are delimited by `$`.  Dollar signs not intended as delimiters should be escaped with a backslash. So if your desired output was *μ*, you'd write `$\mu$` and use `pandoc --mathjax -o out.html`. If $*μ* is what you want, then you'd write `\$$\mu$`.

Another option would be to just insert the desired character directly instead of using LaTeX syntax.

```
echo '$μ' | pandoc -o output.html
```